# Deleting items from a SQLite database

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have an app which has functions where you can add and delete patients. That works fine though I have come across a problem when deleting them.

Here is the sql statement:

```
-(void) deleteTreatmentTypeFromDatabase:(NSString *)deleteid {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"patients.sqlite"];

    sqlite3 *database;

    if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sqlStatement = "delete from records WHERE id = ?";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        NSLog(@"%d", sqlite3_prepare(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL));
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
//            LSAppDelegate *delegate = (LSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//            Record *thisRecord = [delegate.records objectAtIndex:index.row];
            sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [deleteid UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
        if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
        }
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

It is saying no errors in sql when I checked so I am now well and truly stuck.

Please say if you want any more code

Thanks in advance

Comment: And where's your error handling code?

Comment: This line: `NSLog(@"%d", sqlite3_prepare(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL));` it retuens 0 which means no errors

Comment: So you prepare twice? That doesn't make sense. And what if the second prepare fails? That log line is terrible, putting statements with side-effect in logging lines is bad practice - someone will remove that pesky log statement and the code will stop working.

Comment: @OliverCole: I suggest you to use FMDB wrapper class of sqlite for database management. Short lines of code. Easy to use n much more... (https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb):)

Comment: If is says no errors, what is the problem?  (You haven't described any symptoms.)

Comment: Whatever "cookbook" you're using for coding SQLite, throw it out.  Any "tutorial" that doesn't include properly testing for errors is worse than trash.

Comment: const char *sqlStatement = "delete from records WHERE id ='?'";

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
static sqlite3 *database = nil;

static sqlite3_stmt *deleteStmt = nil;

if(deleteStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "delete from Project where ProjectID = ?";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &deleteStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_bind_int(deleteStmt, 1, primaryKey);

    if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(deleteStmt)) 
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    sqlite3_reset(deleteStmt);
```

Comment: I have found what the issue is but don't know how to solve it for some reason when I read the items from the database It is not pulling the recordid or setting it

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
-(void) deleteTreatmentTypeFromDatabase:(NSString *)deleteid {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"patients.sqlite"];

    sqlite3 *database;

    if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from records WHERE id = %@", deleteid];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
          if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE) 
            {
               sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
            }
        }
       sqlite3_close(database);
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for not checking errors.  (Would be -5 if I could do that.  Terrible example.)

Comment: @HotLicks i am new in ios developement may i know what wrong in this code

Comment: What do you do if sqlite3_step (or any of the other sqlite3 calls) fails?  Do you report an error?  No.  Do you call sqlite3_errmsg and display the detailed explanation of the failure?  No.